# Evaluate the area of the region bounded by the ellipse, where is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

[image]

$ (10x^2+6xy+y^2=2)$ => $ ((x/\sqrt2)^{2} + ((3x+y)/\sqrt2))^{2} = 1 $

so if I change the variables to $u$ and $v$,

$u = x/\sqrt2$

$v=  (3x+y)/\sqrt2) $

Then my bounds of integration become $-1 < v < 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-v^{2}} < u < \sqrt{1-v^{2}}$

The  double integral is: $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-v^2}}^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} (u\sqrt2)^{2} \frac12 \,du\,dv$

After a few steps of integration, I am left with:

$ \frac13 \int_{-1}^1 (1-v^2)^{3/2} dv$ which is pretty complicated.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It may be complicated, but I believe it is computable.  Have you considered a trig substitution for $v$, perhaps $v=\sin \alpha$?

Comment: Another possibility is rotating the coordinate system to make the ellipse's axis and then perform integration. You switch the computation problem from the region to the function $x^2$.

Comment: This integral does _not_ represent the area of your ellipse.

Comment: @Bob : In case you haven't noticed, I replaced by answer with a quite different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $u=x/\sqrt{2}$ and $v= (3x+y)/\sqrt{2}$.

The $u$-axis is the set of points where $v=0$, and that is where $3x+y=0$.  That's a line whose slope is $-3$.  The $v$-axis is where $u=0$, and that's the same as $x=0$, so it's the same as the $y$-axis.  Your problem is that

- the $u$- and $v$-axes are not at right angles to each other; and also
- a change of one unit in $x$ corresponds to a change of a different number of units in $u$.

Thus $dx\,dy\ne du\,dv$.  Since the transformation from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ is linear, you'll have $dx\,dy\ne (\text{some constant} \cdot du\,dv)$.  (If it were not linear, then the quantity you multiply by would not be constant, i.e. it would depend on $u$ and $v$.

That's one thing that Jacobians are used for.

Alternatively, you could use a different linear transformation that is actually a rotation, so that the constant is $1$.

**PS:** Draw the rectangle whose vertices are

- $(u,v)=(0,0)$.  This happens when $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
- $(u,v)=(1,0)$.  This happens when $(x,y)=(\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2})$.
- $(u,v)=(0,1)$.  This happens when $(x,y)=(0,\sqrt{2})$.
- $(u,v)=(1,1)$.  This happens when $(x,y)=(\sqrt{2},-2\sqrt{2})$.

You see a parallelogram whose area in the $xy$-plane is $2$. But in the $uv$-plane the area is $1$: it's just the area of a square.  In other words an area of $1$ in the $uv$-plane corresponds to an area of $2$ in the $xy$-plane. That tells you that $dx\,dy=2\,du\,dv$.

Comment: I don't see where my mistake is though :( How can I get the correct change of variables?

Comment: Have you seen Jacobians?

Comment: Yes, but I thought that all that they are used for is to multiply the integrand when converting to polar co-ordinates.

Comment: They are used far more generally.  To explain why $dy\,dx$ becomes $r\,dr\,d\theta$, I don't think I'd even mention Jacobians.  I'd just say that arc length on a circle is radian measure times radius, and the infinitely small increment of radian measure is $d\theta$, and the radius is $r$, so the infinitely small increment of arc length is $r\,d\theta$.  It is at a right angle to the infinitely small change in radius, so the infinitely small area is $(dr)\cdot(r\,d\theta)$.  Jacobians give the same result, but this bit of geometry should also be understood. ${}\qquad{}$